# How do I dynamically display and hide different content within the same div using angular js?

Tags: html, angularjs

I have an auto filled form filled section but when I click the link “**enter manually**” I want it to be replaced by empty form fields (within the same space/spot/div). I also want the link to change to “**return to original**” so that when I click on it, it allows me to return to the original auto filled state with the link "**enter manually"** displaying yet again. See my code below:

```
**Auto-filled section:**

        <div class="form-group">
           <label class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 control-label" for="selectbasic">Product1</label>
           <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
              <input type="text" name="product1" class="form-control" id="productName1" value="Product1">
           </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
           <label class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 control-label" for="selectbasic">Product2</label>
           <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
              <input type="text" name="product2" class="form-control" id="productName2" value="Product2">
           </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
           <label class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 control-label" for="selectbasic"></label>
           <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6" ><a href="">(or enter details manually)</a></div>
        </div>


**Manual Section:**

  <div class="form-group">
           <label class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 control-label" for="selectbasic">Product3</label>
           <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
              <input type="text" name="product3" class="form-control" id="productName3" required="" value="">
           </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
           <label class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 control-label" for="selectbasic">Product4</label>
           <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
              <input type="text" name="product4" class="form-control" id="productName4" required="" value="">
           </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
           <label class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 control-label" for="selectbasic">Product5</label>
           <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
              <input type="text" name="product5" class="form-control" id="productName5" required="" value="">
           </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
           <label class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 control-label" for="selectbasic"></label>
           <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6" ><a href="">(or return to original)</a></div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fiddle demonstrating what you are looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/a0w7z4up/1/

The combination of `ng-show`, `ng-init` and `ng-click` is used to render the replacement of input field.

Comment: thank you for the quick reply & feedback but it's still not replacing the input field (in the same space) as requested. One link doesn't trigger any input field at all and the other triggers it but displays it under the existing field instead of replacing & hiding it.

Answer (score 0):

I did some sample code for you. Please go through into this.

```
   <form >

        <input type="text" ng-model="data.name" />
        <input type="text" ng-model="data.age" />

        <button ng-click="onClick()">{{btnText}}</button>

    </form>
```

In your controller:

```
   var data = {
            name: 'mohit',
            age: 26
        }

        $scope.data = data;
        $scope.btnText = 'Change to Manual';

        $scope.onClick = function () {
            if ($scope.btnText == 'Change to Origional') {
                $scope.data = data;
                $scope.btnText = 'Change to Manual';
            } else {
                $scope.btnText = 'Change to Origional';
                $scope.data = {};
            }
        }
```